# LSI MegaRAID 9271-8i RAID1 disk expansion

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-raid, lsi

I have a RAID1 setup with two 3TB disk, is it possible for me to buy two 4TB disk and expand my DiskGroup?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'll probably lose 2 TB, because only 3 TB will be used on each of the new drives.

Comment: So there is no way to use new space?

Comment: I don't know specifically the LSI MegaRAID 9271-8i, @ThomasG.Lau . Some controllers allow you to create a second RAID-1 of 1 TB on the remaining space, but I would strongly advise against this if you care about performance...